# Using @Override in JUnit4

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I am using Selenium RC and JUnit to write tests. If a `@Test` fails, I would like to take a screen shot, but I want to use a specific screenshot name which is passed from the `Test` class.

Currently I have :

```
@Rule  
public ScreenshotRule email = new ScreenshotRule();  

@Test  
public void testLogin() throws InterruptedException {  
    MyTest someTest = new MyTest(selenium);   
    someTest.someMethod (); // if anything assert fails in this method, i want to take a shot and call it a name which i will pull from the MyTest class.
}
```

Here is the `Screenshot` class :

```
public class ScreenshotRule extends TestWatchman {  
    @Override  
    public void failed(Throwable e, FrameworkMethod method) {  
        System.out.println(method.getName() + " failed");  
        // At this point I wish to take a screenshot and call  
    }  
}
```

So how do I pass a `String` arg from the `MyTest` class to the `Screenshot` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TestWatchman` signature does not permit you to pass any additional information, so you'll have to work with what you have.

For example, the `FrameworkMethod` class has methods to fetch the unit test's `java.lang.reflect.Method` object, so you *could* just use the name of that `Method` object for your screenshot.  It's not what you wanted, but it's better than nothing.

You could also call the `getDeclaringClass()` on the `Method`, to fetch the `Class` representing the test class, but you won't be able to fetch the *instance* of that class, which would be useful.

P.S. I'm not sure what `@Override` has to do with your question. How is it relevant?

Comment: Thanks, I used the getName () method in the end to give some names to my screenshot.